# In struct timespec tv_sec and tv_nsec express the same time in seconds and in nano-seconds or they have to be sum for obtaining the time?

Tags: c, time, timespec

```
double timespec_delta2milliseconds(struct timespec *last, struct timespec *previous)
{
    
 return (last->tv_sec - previous->tv_sec) + (last->tv_nsec - previous->tv_nsec)*pow(10,-3); 

}
```

This function computes the difference (last - previous) and returns the result expressed in milliseconds as a double. I tried a lot of different ways but if I don't do like this i receve in output segmentation fault.
I think that this solution works but it's wrong, someone can help me ?

Comment: [POSIX does not define the usage of the fields in a `struct timespec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html#tag_13_76), so the proper use of the values will depend on how you populated the `struct` variables.

Comment: *`tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` express the same time in seconds and in nano-seconds* No, not at all. *Or they have to be sum for obtaining the time* Yes, that's it.

Comment: Your code adds *microseconds* to *seconds* and claims to return *milliseconds*.

Comment: @AndrewHenle But `clock_settime()` will fail with error `EINVAL` if `tv_nsec` is outside the interval [0,999999999], and `clock_gettime()` will presumably fill in the `struct timespec` so that `tv_nsec` is not out of range.

Comment: `tv_nsec` is typically a 32-bit integer.  So it can handle at most 4294967295 nanoseconds, or about 4.3 seconds.  In ordinary practice it only ever contains values in the range 0..999999999.  But there'd be almost no way for it to practically contain the same time value as `tv_sec`.

Comment: @IanAbbott ...except for an [obscure and rarely-implemented trick](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/posix-clocks.html) to represent leap seconds properly. :-)

Comment: There are various ways to write the correct expression to convert the difference in `struct timespec` values to milliseconds. One way is: `(last->tv_sec - previous->tv_sec + (last->tv_nsec - previous->tv_nsec) * 1e-9) * 1e3`.

Comment: @IanAbbott I try your solution but give me **segmentation fault**

Comment: @Merek_Derek The segmentation fault will be caused by some problem with the `last` and `previous` pointers (somewhere else in the code) and nothing to do with the arithmetic.

Comment: double s = ((double) last->tv_sec) - ((double) previous->tv_sec); //seconds
 double ns = ((double) last->tv_nsec) - ((double) previous->tv_nsec); ; //nanoseconds

 //turn second in millisecond
 s *= 1000;
 //turn nanosec in millisecond
 ns /= pow(10,6);

 return s + ns;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two functions: `sub_timespec()`, which calculates the difference between two time spec values, and `timespec_as_milliseconds()`, which returns the number of milliseconds in a time spec value as an integer.

```
enum { NS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000 };

void sub_timespec(struct timespec t1, struct timespec t2, struct timespec *td)
{
    td->tv_nsec = t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec;
    td->tv_sec  = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;
    if (td->tv_sec > 0 && td->tv_nsec < 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec--;
    }
    else if (td->tv_sec < 0 && td->tv_nsec > 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec++;
    }
}

int64_t timespec_as_milliseconds(struct timespec ts)
{
    int64_t rv = ts.tv_sec * 1000 + ts.tv_nsec / 1000000;
    return rv;
}
```

If you want to round the milliseconds, it gets trickier because you have to worry about carries and negative numbers and so on.  You should not encounter a timespec value where the `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` values have opposite signs (zeros aren't a problem).

In your code, adding `pow(10, -3)` mixes floating point arithmetic with integer arithmetic — usually not a good idea.

If you want a `double` value with up to 3 decimal places of fractional seconds, then you need:

```
double timespec_to_double_milliseconds(struct timespec ts)
{
    double rv = ts.tv_sec + (ts.tv_nsec / 1000000) / 1000.0;
    return rv;
}
```

The first division is (deliberately) integer division; the second gives a floating-point value.  Again, rounding has problems with carrying and so on.

Your function then becomes:

```
double timespec_delta2milliseconds(struct timespec *last, struct timespec *previous)
{
    struct timespec delta = sub_timespec(*last, *previous);
    return timespec_to_double_milliseconds(delta); 
}
```

You can use an extra value in the function so it is easier to print the value returned in a debugger: `double rv = timespec_to_double_milliseconds(delta); return rv;`.

The key idea, though, is to do separate tasks in separate functions.  Taking the difference between two `struct timespec` values is one task; converting a `struct timespec` value to an appropriate `double` is a separate task.  When you can split things into separate tasks, you should.

I often pass `struct timespec` values by value rather than pointer.  The structure size is typically small enough that it is not a stress on the stack or registers.  I return them by value too, which simplifies memory management — YMMV.

And, just in case it isn't clear, the `tv_sec` member of a `struct timespec` contains an integer number of seconds, and the `tv_nsec` contains the fractional part of a second expressed as a number of nanoseconds (0 to 999,999,999).  It requires care in printing the `tv_nsec` value; you need a format such as `%.9ld` to print 9 digits with leading zeros, and the type is `long`.  To print microseconds, divide the `tv_nsec` value by 1,000 and change 9 to 6; to print milliseconds, divide by 1,000,000 and change 9 to 3.  Beware negative values!

Answer (score 2):

The `timespec` structure can handle *fractions* of a second, and the `tv_nsec` is the fractions, represented as nanoseconds.

That means getting the difference between two `timespec` structures isn't as straight-forward as you make it seem in your code.

Here's an example on how to get the difference, returned as a new `timesepc` structure:

```
struct timespec diff_timespec(const struct timespec *time1, const struct timespec *time0)
{
    struct timespec diff = {
        .tv_sec = time1->tv_sec - time0->tv_sec,
        .tv_nsec = time1->tv_nsec - time0->tv_nsec
    };

    if (diff.tv_nsec < 0)
    {
        diff.tv_nsec += 1000000000;
        diff.tv_sec--;
    }

    return diff;
}
```

Comment: I have to return a double not a struct

Comment: @Merek_Derek You could modify your own `timespec_delta2milliseconds` to call this more generic function, and use the returned `timespec` structure to convert the result to a `double` value. Remember that it makes best sense if *both* members are converted to a common unit (be it nanoseconds, seconds, or something in between) to make it easier to add them.

Comment: you're right but I have to turn a double :)

Comment: @Merek_Derek `tv_sec + (tv_nsec * 1000000000.0)`?